# Samsung GT-I5500 hangs after boot

Tags: 2.2-froyo, boot, samsung-galaxy-5

After booting I receive this message:

```
Process system is not responding:
1. Close
2. Wait
```

Whatever I choose I got only black screen.
I'm using official unbranded latest rom -> 2.2.
[List of installed apps.](http://pl.appbrain.com/user/QuantumDamage/apps-on-the-phone)

Comment: Can you clarify - what "_official unbranded latest rom_" are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

How long are you waiting? Sometimes it can take a *really* long time to load.

What you'll probably have to end up doing:
Turn off your phone, then start up in Safe Mode by pressing and holding the big black dpad key plus the power button. Keep pressing them until you see "Safe Mode" on the screen. Uninstall any apps you've installed since your last restart. If you're rooted, do a nandroid backup first.

Comment: The OP's handset is not rooted!